# Python: Pulling values from nested JSON fields

Tags: python, json

With Python I'm pulling a nested json, and I'm seeking to parse it via a loop and write the data to a csv. The structure of the json is below. The values I'm after are in the `view` list, labeled `user_id` and `message`, and then under nested field `replies` the fields `user_id` and `message` again.

```
    ],
  "view": [
    {
      "id": 109205,
      "user_id": 6354,
      "parent_id": null,
      "created_at": "2020-11-03T23:32:49Z",
      "updated_at": "2020-11-03T23:32:49Z",
      "rating_count": null,
      "rating_sum": null,
      "message": "message text1",
      "replies": [
        {
          "id": 109298,
          "user_id": 5457,
          "parent_id": 109205,
          "created_at": "2020-11-04T19:42:59Z",
          "updated_at": "2020-11-04T19:42:59Z",
          "rating_count": null,
          "rating_sum": null,
          "message": "message text2"
        },
        {
         #json continues
```

I'm able to pull the values for the fields under `view` with the following code:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

url = URL
headers = {'Authorization' : 'Bearer KEY)
data = r.json()

message_length = len(data["view"])

#prints values in user_id field
for item in range(message_length):
    print((data['view'][item]['user_id']))

#prints values for message field
for item in range(message_length):
    print((data['view'][item]['message']))
```

However, I'm struggling to produce the nested values under `replies`. At least one of the `view` entries does not contain the `replies` field, and I keep get a `list index out of range` error when I try:

```
reply_lengh = len(data["view"][message_length]['replies'])

print(reply_length)
```

I have also tried to print the number of replies per `replies` field, but at least one of the `view` entries doesn't have any `replies`:

```
for item in range(message_length):
    print((len(data["view"][item]["replies"])))
```

Yields the following output:

```
4
4
4
5
5
2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\danie\Desktop\Python\Streamlit\Experiment_4_0.py", line 47, in <module>
    print((len(data["view"][item]["replies"])))
KeyError: 'replies'
1
1
2
1
1
1
```

Any suggestions on how to proceed to pull values under the nested field `replies`? All advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: The 'view' key has a value which is a list of dictionaries. Each of those dictionaries has a 'replies' key which also has a value which is a list of dictionaries. Thus, assuming that 'view' is a top-level key, the following would be valid:-
data['view'][0]['replies'][0]['message']
Where you see the zero indices in my example should help you to understand how you need to construct your loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `try` and `except` block:

```
for item in range(message_length):
    try:
        print((len(data["view"][item]["replies"])))

        replies = data["view"][item]["replies"]
        for item in replies:
            print(item['user_id'], item['message'])

    except:
        print("key not found")
```

Comment: Many thanks! That works. Any suggestions how would I structure the syntax to pull values from the `user_id` and `message` fields under `replies`?

Comment: You can have a look at my updated answer and see it helps.

Comment: That did it! Much appreciated!